# UIView returns the same size depending of the device

Tags: ios

I have a dynamic UIView based on the `height` of a superView by using a multiplier (in my case 0.125 the height of the superview).

For any reason, when I want to recover the value of the view:

`let rangeSliderHeight = playerView.bounds.size.height * 0.5`

I get the same size with my iPhone 5 and my iPad, even though visually, on iPad is much more big than iPhone.

There's no autolayout option to define custom rules for iPads or iPhones for this case, since the library I use builds the element from code.

Is there any posibility to get the real size of the `UIView` depending of the device?

Comment: do you mean , 'how to get current device screensize' ?

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to retrieve the size of the device?

Comment: @Christoph in the `viewDidLoad()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `playerView.bounds.size.height` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`. At that point the views will have been laid out and you can retrieve the actual size.

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted! Now I can get the size of any `@IBOutlet` `UIView` defined. Thanks!